# my php upload script no result ?

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload

i have problem on my php file upload script , i am trying to upload a file , then store a location on mysql database.

the problem is when i am trying to upload any file , the action.php doesn't give me any message whether it success or failed !

here is my html form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> 
 E-mail: <input type="text" name = "email"><br> 
 Phone: <input type="text" name = "phone"><br> 
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Add"> 
 </form>
```

here is my add.php code:

```
     <?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "/images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $email=$_POST['email']; 
 $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123123") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("bom") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bom` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$pic')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

mysql conntection is working 100%, i have make sure of that , also i have a folder called " images " on my script folder , where is the problem ?

Comment: What does basic debugging tell you? What does `$_POST` contain (do a `print_r($_POST);`? Are there any errors from the query (use `echo mysql_error()` to see them? Is error reporting activated (use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to make sure it is)?

Comment: Also, your database query is susceptible to SQL injection http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: tried , but still nothing , the problem i only got a white page with no message , and the file is not on the images folder

Comment: I'm fairly sure you don't have error reporting activated.

Comment: now it says Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\AppServ\www\PromBom\add.php on line 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assumed that the file upload actually worked. You should have at least some minimal error handling before you do anything with the upload:

```
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'])
}
```

The error codes are document [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)